# How to deal with direct replies from mailing lists?

Tags: gmail-filters

I'm using filtering to label and immediately archive emails from mailing lists (i.e. where the "To:" field is a mailing list address). However, when I interact with the list, I wish for follow-up answers or comments to appear in my Inbox, or that I be notified in some other way. Usually, my address will be in the cc or to field in these cases.

How can this be achieved with Google Mail?

Comment: You can probably get a more detailed suggestion if you include your current filter in your question.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought was to include a filter on the subject. eg. `subject:-"re: "` (where the subject does not contain `re:` in the case of replies). However, Gmail seems to ignore the colon and space (`:`) in the filter, so filtering just on `re` is far too encompassing.

As a workaround you could perhaps manually include a *trigger* word in the subject or message body and filter on that, eg. `-{TRIGGER_WORD}` (does not contain "TRIGGER_WORD"). This is of course assuming that replies to your reply contain your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can key off your address being in the cc: field by excluding it in your filter.

```
-cc:youremailaddress@gmail.com
```